# Running python code in a shell with VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using shift-enter, I can run a single line of code from some script in VS Code (using the standard Microsoft Python extension).  If not already open, it pops open an ipython shell, and runs the line of code in that shell.  The same works if I have consecutive non-indented lines of code — I just highlight all of them, and hit shift-enter.  But if I want to any slightly more complicated piece of code, it fails.

For example, suppose I have

```py
def bla(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y
```

(It does matter that there are three lines here.)

Now I want to use that function in the shell, so I highlight the whole thing, hit shift-enter, and get this:

```
In [1]: def bla(x):
     ...:         y = x + 1
     ...:             return y
  Cell In[1], line 3
    return y
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Evidently the pasting process adds indents that can't be there.  This sort of thing works just fine with the Julia extension, so I'm surprised the (presumably more widely used) python extension doesn't work.

Is there some setting or something that I could change to get this to work, or is this just not something Microsoft want to support?

Comment: Never used that before, but seems to work as expected on my end. The one difference is I don't get the "Cell" bit, which is a bit weird.  Have you tried restarting VSCode? It is a Microsoft product after all.

Comment: Yeah, I restart every day (and just this minute), and always run into this.  It's interesting that yours is so different, though.  Is your shell ipython or just python?  (I don't think I changed any config to make mine ipython, but maybe.)

Comment: Even though I'm running it with ipython, I still haven't had the problem you said if I just used the three lines of code you provided to reproduce the problem. By the way, the latest python extension has changed shortcuts `shift+enter`. It will open a new python terminal instead of interactive. I guess that's what differentiates you from Anonymous.

Comment: Ah, of course, that hadn't occurred to me. Yes, python shell on my end, not ipython.